# MVC Routing the Index page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a very simple MVC application:

When I type:

```
http://locahost:8080
```

the following route in the routeconfig takes me to the Home controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When I type the following, I get 404 error.

```
http://locahost:8080/JohnDoe
```

I want to map this request to Home Controller's Get Action with name function (see below). How do I go about doing that?

```
    public Person Get(string name)
    {
        PersonRespository db = new PersonRespository();
        return db.GetPerson(name);
    }
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Your action name is Index, yet your method is called Get. Call your method Index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Custom",
    url: "{name}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Get"
    });
```